# How to flatten a relational database extract to single rows in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a challenge that I can't quite figure out the best solution for. I need to take a very long data set that comes from a relational database that looks like this:

```
Filename    Data        Fields     Values
file1       12345678    ID         123-123-123
file1       12345678    Type       Photoshop
file1       12345678    Keyword    red
file1       12345678    Keyword    yellow
file1       12345678    Keyword    blue
file1       12345678    Basket     7642
file2       87654321    ID         321-321-321
file2       87654321    Keyword    red
file2       87654321    Keyword    orange
file2       87654321    Keyword    purple
file2       87654321    Keyword    green
file2       87654321    Usage      User Name
file2       87654321    Basket     6543
```

And need to consolidate it in a more field / value pairs way, so that it  looks like this:

```
Filename    Data1       Values         ID             Type         Keyword                    Basket    Usage
file1       12345678    123-123-123    123-123-123    Photoshop    red,yellow,blue            7642
file2       87654321    321-321-321    321-321-321                 red,orange,purple,green    6543      User Name
```

What I have been able to do is to expand the fields, and condense the multi-value fields, but the last operation, condensing all similar-filenamed rows to one per eludes me. I only have access  to Excel Mac 2011, for reference.

Does anyone know how to perform this last step or do the entire process in a more elegant fashion?

[Here](http://www25.zippyshare.com/v/11125107/file.html) is the example file.

Comment: Are you looking to do this purely in SQL/DB layer or are you capable of using a non-db language to aid you?

Comment: I didn't look at this for too long, but maybe a pivot table could start moving you in the right direction??

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that your data has been rearranged as in A:H below, then `=IF(A1=A2,I1&", "&F2,F2)` in I2 and copied down should give you the concatenation of column F by Filename. Then with `=A2=A3` in J2 copied down, Paste Special Values for ColumnI and delete rows where J shows TRUE should provide the required condensation:

[image: SO20618025 example]